# Access 2007 - Lock users out of form design mode

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

Is there a way to lock users out of being able to view and edit a form in design mode in Access 2007?

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach it is distributing a ACCDE file to users.

- Database Tools... Make ACCDE
- Save your Database as an .accde file for distribution.

Here's the description from the Access help files:

> An .accde file is the Office Access 2007 version of the .mde file in
>   earlier versions of Access. It is a locked-down version of the
>   original .accdb file. If the .accdb file contained any VBA code, only
>   the compiled code is included in the .accde file — as a result, the
>   VBA code cannot be viewed or modified by the user. Also, .accde file
>   users do not have permissions to make design changes to forms or
>   reports.

This allows you to keep the original ACCDB file, while providing user access to the ACCDE file. Of course, this implies creating a new ACCDE file whenever a change is made to the ACCDB. For this reason, you might want to keep your data in a separate, linked ACCDB database and your forms in the ACCDE. This will allow you to replace the ACCDE files at any moment without losing any data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to ONLY allow the users to use the Access Runtime, which disables ALL designing tools. It's free and doesn't require a separate copy of Office Professional or Microsoft Access to run